# Hover button and fill from left to right with :after

Tags: html, css

When I hover on the button the box fills but the text doesn't show, and I believe it is because the background is over it. How can I fix this?

```html
        <div class="banner">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-6">
                        <h2>We Design and Develop</h2>
                        <p>We are a new design studio based in USA. We have over 20 years of combined experience, and know a thing or two about designing websites and mobile apps.</p>
                        <a href="#">CONTACT US</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
```

```css
.banner a {
 background: none;
 padding: 20px 35px;
 color: #10c9c3;
 font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
 border: 2px solid #10c9c3;
 transition: 0.3s;
 position: relative;
}

.banner a:hover, .banner a:active {
 color: white;
}

.banner a:after {
 content: '';
 position: absolute;
 transition: all 0.3s;
 width: 0%;
 height: 100%;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 color: white;
 z-index: 0;
}

.banner a:hover:after {
 width: 100%;
 background: #10c9c3;
}
```

```html
<div class="banner">
<a href="#">I am a link</a>
</div>
```

The result I want to get is the text to change its color to white and show above the background.

Comment: and yet still no `HTML` included...

Answer (score 0):

Set z-index to -1 for your background, it should be under the `<a>` tag

```
.banner a:after {
    ...

    z-index: -1;
}
```

in your implementation background render above `<a>` tag

Comment: When I add the z-index: -1; the background doesn't appear

Comment: It`s a working example https://jsbin.com/nujulabili/1/edit?html,css,output

Comment: I have absolutely the same code and it does not work.(I added the HTML on top)

Comment: Can you look at devtools, maybe some of styles override the z-index property?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
    .banner a {
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #10c9c3 50%, white 50%);
    background-size: 200% 100%;
    background-position: right bottom; 
    padding: 20px 35px;
    color: #10c9c3;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    border: 2px solid #10c9c3;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    position: relative;
}

.banner a:hover, .banner a:active {
    color: white;
    background-position: left bottom;
}
```

Preview: https://codepen.io/ruelminds/pen/PMONYd